# Replicate dataclasses-style __init__ autocreation from annotations

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

```
from dataclasses import dataclass 

@dataclass
class A:
    number: int
    string: str 
    default_not_hinted_arg = None
    
A() # class A(
    #     number: int,
    #     string: str
    # )
```

Is it possible to replicate this behavior, but for a custom non-dataclass model?

Let's say I have the following:

```
class A:
    number: int
    string: str 
    ... # N arbitrary type-hinted arguments
    default_not_hinted_arg = None
    
    def __init__(**kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

I tried to check the source code for `dataclass` but didn't have any luck for type-hinting generation. Is it possible to implement this in pure python? It seems to me that the process involves copying the object `A.__annotations__` and somehow transferring it to `__init__(**kwargs)`, but I'm at a loss on how exactly to achieve this, and my attempts didn't work with mypy.

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0681 is implemented in pyright and mypy

Comment: @dROOOze I might be wrong, I think the topic was from an actual implementation standpoint (not necessary type checking with `dataclass_transform`)

Comment: Correct, I want to understand how it's implemented and replicate it.